# Excel to perform addition if cell is even or odd

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've had no luck with a formula to lookup a cell determine if it's odd or even and then perform a function.

The formula will need to lookup A6, if the value is even then it will take B5-3, if the value is odd it will take B5-2.

I've tried this:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(A6),(B5-3), (ISODD(A6),B5-2))
```

I'm using open office org and it continues to return an error. I'm a newbie so please be gentle. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (don't need to put ISODD - if ISEVEN fails then A6 must be odd), and use semicolon as delimiter in Open Office:-

```
=IF(ISEVEN(A6);B5-3;B5-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

No **IF**s are needed, use:

**=B5-3+ISODD(A6)**

Comment: Neat! Hopefully it is instructive to have both answers.

Comment: @TomSharpe Thanks Tom.......I posted to show that *IsOdd()* can be used numerically as well as logically.